# posting from a remote (cross domain) to laravel doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, post, laravel-4, cross-domain

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("http://domain.com/laravel/livefeed",
    {
      incid:"DonaldDuck",
      id:"Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }); 
  });
```

thats my button, when I do click it says `access to restricted URI denied` domain.com/laravel is a laravel site. 
I have another script that is not laravel where I set my headers to :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

and this works perfectly. How do I do it in laravel is the issue I tried multiple ways and it doesn't work it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate and configure this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors. It's a very solid package that will allow you to configure CORS requests on your Laravel site.

Comment: I have it installed it doesn't work for me. I posted this question AFTER I tried that package

Comment: when I post from another domain it doesnt allow it to post.  when i post to a test.php that has the allow origin in headers set to * then that works.I did setup laravel-cors properly still wouldnt work

Comment: right now its returning 405 method not allowed with laravel-cors